# Get value from span - I want click the "Check all" option from the below code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Check all

I would click on the "check all" link from the above html code. Kindly help

Comment: <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-multiselect-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-multiselect-hasfilter">
    <div class="ui-multiselect-filter">
        <ul class="ui-helper-reset">
            <li>
                <a class="ui-multiselect-all" href="#">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check" />
                    <span>Check all</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <li class="ui-multiselect-close">
        </ul>

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to click on the "check all" link:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-icon.ui-icon-check > span")).click();
```